# inserting into array of json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have an array of json objects and i have a select input what i want to do it is when i choose something from that select input it adds it to that array and at the same time when i re select the same item it won't add it again but didn't find how to make it

this is my array initialized in the state :

```
      this.state = {    
        Modules_SubModules_Array: [{ "Module": "", "SubModules": [] }],  
    };
```

and this is the function that i use to make the insert to that array :

```
  Affect_Module_Submodule = (currentModuleTitle) => {
    if (this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array.some(item => item.Module == 
      currentModuleTitle)) {
        console.log("it includes")
    }

    else if (!this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array.some(item => item.Module 
   == currentModuleTitle)) {
        console.log("it doesnt include")
    }
}
```

the currentModuleTitle is the item that i picked from the select input i want to test if that array contains already that value it won't add it and if it's not it adds it iam stuck at it a while now if you can help me i could appreciate that

Comment: Pointless to run the same `some()` test twice

Comment: I assume that your actual problem is with nested modules, right? Your example should reflect that problem then, in other words: Ad an example that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Affect_Module_Submodule = (currentModuleTitle) => {
  if (this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array.findIndex(item => item.Module ==
      currentModuleTitle) < 0) {
    this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array.push({
      "Module": currentModuleTitle,
      "SubModules": []
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked i just replaced the push by splice so i can edit the first intial object

Answer (score 1):

You could flatten the modules:

```
 const flatModules = modules => modules.flatMap(module => [module.Module, flatModules(module.Sub_Modules)]);
```

Then you can easily do:

```
flatModules(this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array).includes(currentModuleTitle)
```

Comment: u mean i just put the flatModules inside and if statement and that's it ?

Comment: @AOUADISlim the second part of the answer is what you should put in your if statement (`.includes` returns a boolean)

Comment: well it actually shows me an error Cannot read property 'flatMap' of undefined when i tried to test         console.log(flatModules(this.state.Modules_SubModules_Array).includes(currentModuleTitle))

Comment: Thats because there are some obejcts in the tree were `module.Sub_Modules` is not set. Honestly you should change your datastructure to be consistent then

Comment: if u have a better idea i will be happy to try it